# data point and ticks are not aligned in highstock line graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The data point plotted is not matching exactly with the tick or the ticks are not placed at the data points. when I reduce the range with the navigator I having this problem seen very clearly. Is there any way so that i can set that ticks will be coming for Saturdays or any day which i specify?

Comment: here I'm trying to plot values of every saturday but the ticks are coming on monday

Comment: I have a similar issue and fixed it by setting tickmarkPlacement to 'on' (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement). Not sure if that will help in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tickInterval http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval and define pointStart http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart. You can also use other solution by using http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: I've tried the same, it worked until certain extent but not completely.

Comment: setting those options done the work only when I select the data of small date range i.e 5 to 6 weeks till a medium date range of 10 to 15 weeks in my case. but when the range gets on bigger and especially when it is more than 25 weeks, data is not matching the tick position